# JSON.parse(Fetch_Get_JSON_Data) Within Async Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, asynchronous, fetch

I stumbled across an issue where I was trying to parse an incoming .JSON object in an async Fetch-Get request, it gave me the following error in the browser:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at window.getData (Login.js:32)
    at async window.login (Login.js:38
```

This is the relevant pre-browserified code:

```
window.getData = async function()
{
var response = await fetch("https://goldengates.club:3000/api/blocks");
var chain = await response.json();
var chainParsed = JSON.parse(chain);
return chainParsed;
}

window.login = async function()
{
  const chain = await getData(); //might need to parse this
  console.log(chain);
}
```

The login function above gets called once a button is pressed in the front end.

I am obviously doing something wrong and it's bugging me, I am fairly new to asynch and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `response.json()` parses the string data to a JavaScript object. `JSON.parse()` is trying to parse already parsed data. Fix it by deleting the `JSON.parse()` line, and returning `chain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the error is coming up due to the last two lines in `windows.getData`.

Incase your motive was to return the properties from that api mentioned in `var` response.

```
const url = ""https://goldengates.club:3000/api/blocks"";

window.getData = async () => 
{
var response = await fetch(url);
var chain = await response.json();

return (
{chain.map((everyChain) => {
const { timestamp, lasthash, hash, data, nounce, difficulty, type } = everyChain;
   return everyChain;
 }});
}
```